# Excel/VBA - Extracting parts of a sentence

Tags: excel, vba

I have been looking to find a solution to my issue quite a bit of time, so I decided to ask you guys as my knowledge in VBA is very noobish.

So what I am trying to do is extracting specific key values from a sentence in excel :

For example, I am receiving this exact type of string and I have to divide this to concatenate information into a sentence (The concatenate thing is ok) :

**54841351, Material, Line:87, Color:Red, reason of the problem**

Another parameter, the length of each field (line, color, etc) is **not** always the same

I tried using RIGHT,LEFT,MID functions, but as the length is changing, I am always ending up modifying all one by one.

What i'd like to do is to be able to extract the "Red" part for example (And the "87" and the "reason", but I think it is the same problem), without taking the length into account.

I think VBA is mandatory here, but I may be wrong.

Would you guys have an idea ?

Thank you in advance!

Regards
Shaia

Comment: What does extract/divide mean in this case? Do you want the result in 3 cells? Do you want it in one cell like this: 87, Red, reason? Or do you want to incorporate it directly into your 'concatenation' formula?

Comment: You may be able to use the split function - if they're always separated by comma

Comment: Use Split() on the comma to get the individual parts, then you can use Split() again (using ":") to get Line and Color

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you want an aproximation with VBA, you may benefit from function SPLIT

> **[Split function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/split-function)**

This is just an example code handling your string to get some values:

```
Sub test()
Dim str As String

str = "54841351, Material, Line:87, Color:Red, reason of the problem"

Debug.Print Split(str, "Color:")(1) 'this will return all chars AFTER string 'color:'
Debug.Print Split(str, "Color:")(0) 'this will return all chars BEFORE string 'color:'

Debug.Print Split(Split(str, "Color:")(1), ",")(0) 'this will return all chars AFTER string 'color:' and then all chars BEFORE first comma found
Debug.Print Split(Split(str, "Line:")(1), ",")(0) 'this will return all chars AFTER string 'line:' and then all chars BEFORE first comma found

'Just as a suggestion, I like to combine this with TRIM to delete extra blanks if they appear (not in this case)

Debug.Print Trim(Split(Split(str, "Color:")(1), ",")(0)) 'this will return all chars AFTER string 'color:' and then all chars BEFORE first comma found
Debug.Print Trim(Split(Split(str, "Line:")(1), ",")(0)) 'this will return all chars AFTER string 'line:' and then all chars BEFORE first comma found

'If you want to keep the variable name (color, line) then you can just do

Debug.Print Trim(Split(str, ",")(3)) 'color
Debug.Print Trim(Split(str, ",")(2)) 'line

End Sub
```

The output I get on inmediate/debugger Window is:
[image]

Comment: Hello,Thank you all for your answers!! Split Function is something that I didn't know, I will try this ASAP and let you know! but extracting all those values seems to be the closest to what I am trying to do :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without VBA. If your input phrases are in a column in your spreadsheet, you first need to separate your values into individual columns, either by using comma-delimited text to columns, or using a series of helper cells. If using helper cells, for each value you want to separate out, you need the character number of the appropriate comma in the original string. The first one would simply be:

FIND(",",A1)

Let's assume that goes in B1. Then in C1,you enter his formula:

LEFT(A1,B1-1)...to get everything before the first comma.

Next, in D1, you enter this formula:

FIND(",",A1,B1+1) ...to get the character number of the next comma. In E1, enter your first MID formula to get the info between the first comma and second comma like so:

MID(A1,B1+1,D1-B1-2)

the -1 and -2 are in there to eliminate the commas and spaces and you may have to adjust those numbers to fit your data.

Repeat the above two steps for each comma in your base text, then add your CONCATENATE formula in the rightmost column and you should be golden. This will work as long as you have the same number of comma-separated phrases in your original text.

VBA is also an option but I would personally use the formula approach here unless your dataset is massive.

Comment: It could work partially. Just as suggestion, some of these formulas should be wrapped around TRIM or it will return leading blanks, like `MID(A1,B1+1,D1-B1-2)`. Also, I think `MID(A1,B1+1,D1-B1-2)` should be `MID(A1,B1+1,D1-B1-1)` or it will not extract the char `l` at end of word

Comment: Hello, thank you for your answer, my dataset is indeed massive, that's why I am trying to optimize as much as possible as I can't check each line one by one, If an error slip into the list, I have high chances to not detect it.